# Android Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

How to download file from Amazon web Services S3 bucket in a specific folder.

As of now, I am import amazon transfer Utility project sample in my android studio and it's working fine no problem but whenever I download a  file from AWS-S3 bucket the file downloaded in a default external storage location.
So, I want the file will be download in a specific folder like storage/folder_name/file_name.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. I am using this in my project able to download image to particular folder..

```
 File imageImage = new File(mContext.getDir(USER_PROFILE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)+ ImageName).getAbsoluteFile();
 Download(checkImage,Constants.AMAZON_BUCKET_IMAGE,ImageName);

/**
 * To download the image from the Amazon S3 bucket and store the image locally to the particular directory
 * @param DownloadingImagePath Source path of the image file to be stored
 * @param ImageName Image file name / Object key of Amazon S3
 * @param ImageBucket Amazon S3 bucket name
*/
public void Download(File DownloadingImagePath,String ImageBucket,String ImageName){
try{
      AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
      AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
                java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");
                s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
                s3.setEndpoint("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/");
                TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, mContext);
                TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(ImageBucket, ImageName, DownloadingImagePath);
                observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                        //Log.e("Amazon Stats",state.name());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

                    }
                });
                } catch (Exception ignored){
            }
        }
```

Comment: You'r welcome . Please if this answer help you please accept it. It may help other to  solve how are looking for same..Enjoy coding.........

Comment: Hello Andan, ..I'm able to do so which you suggest to me..one more question...i have so many file in S3 bucket but i have download only those file which I clicked...So, i want download all the file from S3 bucket in my loacal/external storage.....Any further suggestion considerable..

Comment: My images are saved in a folder inside the bucket, so do I have to mention the folder as the bucket name or mention it in the key?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) to download a file to any location you would like.
Or use a CLI tool like [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)